# Is the set of all invertible 2x2 matrices a subspace of all 2x2 matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is the set of all invertible 2 x 2 matrices a subspace of all 2 x 2 matrices? If not, can someone give me a counterexample to disprove this statement.

Comment: $0\text{}\text{}$

Comment: consider $I_2+(-I_2)$

Comment: or $A + (-A)$ for any invertible matrix $A$

Answer (score 6):

If the invertible $2×2$ real matrices formed a subspace of $\mathbf M_{2×2}(\mathbb R)$, then the zero matrix would have to be in that subspace by definition, but the zero matrix is not invertible.

However, under *matrix multiplication* the invertible $2×2$ matrices do form a *group*, the general linear group $GL(2,\mathbb R)$.

Answer (score 3):

Two arguments can be taken to disprove this statement.

(1) First note that the zero matrix should be included by every subspace of $\Bbb R^{2\times 2}$. Since $0$-matrix is not invertible, therefore the set of invertible matrices is not a vector space.

(2) The following two matrices are invertible$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\\B=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}$$though $\lambda(A+B)$ is not for $\lambda\in \Bbb R$.